# STL re-implementation with concepts

Tags: c++, stl, c++-concepts

Quite recently gcc implemented an experimental support for C++17 standard, part of which are concepts. I read about it and immediately got hooked up with all the goodies it can provide. But my question is - will current STL implementation get a face-lift using concepts? Is so, is there some estimate about when?

From my point of view, it would be great if at least the `algorithm` collection was re-implemented using concepts to avoid unnecessarily long error messages when there is a missing operator or something.

**Edit:**
Apparently I got it wrong about concepts being part of C++17. Anyway the question about STL being upgraded with concepts is I believe still valid.

Comment: Concepts are not part of C++17. There is a separate Technical Specification for concepts, though. Consequently, there will also be no change for the standard library in C++17. Ask again for C++20.

Comment: Oh, I got it wrong then, I thought it made it to C++17 when gcc-6 release notes listed it next to implementation of C++17. It seemed like they just want to stress it out.

Comment: IIRC, the Concepts TS only defines the language support for concepts, but does not consider applying them at all (to the standard library or otherwise). This is to make the TS leaner and easier to push forward though the acceptance phases.

Comment: The GCC release notes definitely do not claim to "implement C++17". That would be preposterous, given that C++17 has not been published yet, nor has even a final draft been produced yet.

Comment: * implement some features from C++17